# Gutenberg MediaUpload disappears in editor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm trying to create a custom block in Gutenberg that involves uploading an image. The problem I'm having is that `render` in `MediaUpload` isn't working. I think I'm missing something, but I can't find it.

Whenever I try to put a `MediaUpload` element in a block, it comes up empty. In the code below, if you inspect it, you'll see the `<div class="image-test">` but nothing will be inside it.

I tried simplifying to the code below to make sure nothing was interfering with it, but it still didn't work for me.

This is the `block.js` code:

```
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const { MediaUpload, MediaUploadCheck } = wp.editor;
const { Button } = wp.components;

registerBlockType( 'custom/image-test', {
    title: 'Image Test',
    icon: 'warning',
    category: 'custom-blocks',

    edit( { attributes, className, setAttributes } ) {
        return (
            <div className="image-test">
                <MediaUploadCheck>
                    <MediaUpload
                        onSelect={ media => console.log( media.length ) }
                        render={ ({ open }) => (
                            <Button onClick={ open }>
                                Open Media Library
                            </Button>
                        )}
                    />
                </MediaUploadCheck>
            </div>
        );
    },

    save( { attributes } ) {
        return (
            <div class="image-test">
                <p>Image Test</p>
            </div>
        );
    },
} );
```

This is where I declare the block in functions:

```
function image_test_block(){
    wp_register_script(
        'image-test-script', // name of script
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/block-image-test.js', // path to script
        array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-element', 'wp-editor', 'wp-components' ) // dependencies
    );

    register_block_type('custom/image-test', array(
        'editor_script' => 'image-test-script'
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'image_test_block', 10, 0 );
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, MediaUploadCheck hasn't been a official WP component as far as I can remember. Here's the [proposal ticket](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/9298)

Use block dev tools like [create guten block](https://github.com/ahmadawais/create-guten-block) for saving yourself the hassle of configuration. I'm not sure about your script enqueue, most probably you are adding your assets via incorrect hook.

This a working recipe card with mediaUpload component in it.

```
const { __, setLocaleData } = wp.i18n;
const {
    registerBlockType,
} = wp.blocks;
const {
    RichText,
    MediaUpload,
} = wp.editor;
const { Button } = wp.components;

setLocaleData( window.gutenberg_examples_05_esnext.localeData, 'gutenberg-examples' );

registerBlockType( 'gutenberg-examples/example-05-recipe-card-esnext', {
    title: __( 'Example: Recipe Card (esnext)', 'gutenberg-examples' ),
    icon: 'index-card',
    category: 'layout',
    attributes: {
        title: {
            type: 'array',
            source: 'children',
            selector: 'h2',
        },
        mediaID: {
            type: 'number',
        },
        mediaURL: {
            type: 'string',
            source: 'attribute',
            selector: 'img',
            attribute: 'src',
        },
        ingredients: {
            type: 'array',
            source: 'children',
            selector: '.ingredients',
        },
        instructions: {
            type: 'array',
            source: 'children',
            selector: '.steps',
        },
    },
    edit: ( props ) => {
        const {
            className,
            attributes: {
                title,
                mediaID,
                mediaURL,
                ingredients,
                instructions,
            },
            setAttributes,
        } = props;
        const onChangeTitle = ( value ) => {
            setAttributes( { title: value } );
        };

        const onSelectImage = ( media ) => {
            setAttributes( {
                mediaURL: media.url,
                mediaID: media.id,
            } );
        };
        const onChangeIngredients = ( value ) => {
            setAttributes( { ingredients: value } );
        };

        const onChangeInstructions = ( value ) => {
            setAttributes( { instructions: value } );
        };

        return (
            <div className={ className }>
                <RichText
                    tagName="h2"
                    placeholder={ __( 'Write Recipe title…', 'gutenberg-examples' ) }
                    value={ title }
                    onChange={ onChangeTitle }
                />
                <div className="recipe-image">
                    <MediaUpload
                        onSelect={ onSelectImage }
                        allowedTypes="image"
                        value={ mediaID }
                        render={ ( { open } ) => (
                            <Button className={ mediaID ? 'image-button' : 'button button-large' } onClick={ open }>
                                { ! mediaID ? __( 'Upload Image', 'gutenberg-examples' ) : <img src={ mediaURL } alt={ __( 'Upload Recipe Image', 'gutenberg-examples' ) } /> }
                            </Button>
                        ) }
                    />
                </div>
                <h3>{ __( 'Ingredients', 'gutenberg-examples' ) }</h3>
                <RichText
                    tagName="ul"
                    multiline="li"
                    placeholder={ __( 'Write a list of ingredients…', 'gutenberg-examples' ) }
                    value={ ingredients }
                    onChange={ onChangeIngredients }
                    className="ingredients"
                />
                <h3>{ __( 'Instructions', 'gutenberg-examples' ) }</h3>
                <RichText
                    tagName="div"
                    multiline="p"
                    className="steps"
                    placeholder={ __( 'Write the instructions…', 'gutenberg-examples' ) }
                    value={ instructions }
                    onChange={ onChangeInstructions }
                />
            </div>
        );
    },
    save: ( props ) => {
        const {
            className,
            attributes: {
                title,
                mediaURL,
                ingredients,
                instructions,
            },
        } = props;
        return (
            <div className={ className }>
                <RichText.Content tagName="h2" value={ title } />

                {
                    mediaURL && (
                        <img className="recipe-image" src={ mediaURL } alt={ __( 'Recipe Image', 'gutenberg-examples' ) } />
                    )
                }

                <RichText.Content tagName="h2" className="ingredients" value={ ingredients } />

                <RichText.Content tagName="div" className="steps" value={ instructions } />
            </div>
        );
    },
} );
```

Your mediaUload component is missing media ID, mandatory **onSelect** function and also you are outputting value in search console.